# problema de formato consulta linq to xml

Tags: asp.net, linq, xml

Realizo la siguiente consulta linq sobre un archivo xml, y me muestra este resultado, como puedo quitar las llaves y el texto (codigo=), estoy programando en asp.net c#.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la consulta linq

```
var q = (from r in LicitacionesD.Descendants("Licitacion")
                     where r.Element("CodigoEstado").Value == "8"
                     select new
                     {
                         codigo = r.Element("CodigoExterno").Value + " " + r.Element("Nombre").Value

                     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes construir solo el texto como C# `IEnumerable<string>` con la consulta

```
from r in LicitacionesD.Descendants("Licitacion")
                     where r.Element("CodigoEstado").Value == "8"
                     select r.Element("CodigoExterno").Value + " " + r.Element("Nombre").Value
```

Si sabes que solo existe un elemento o si solo quieres encontrar el primer elemento puedes utilizar

```
string codigo = (from r in LicitacionesD.Descendants("Licitacion")
                         where r.Element("CodigoEstado").Value == "8"
                         select r.Element("CodigoExterno").Value + " " + r.Element("Nombre").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```